# how to calculate prevalence with given data

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have a dataset called 'disease' and I would like to calculate prevalence of certain disease using given dataset.
I have two column 'disease_id' and 'person_id' and I know there are total number of samples are 1453477 and I am going to filter certain disease using 'where' statement to 'disease_id'.

As I know the total number of sample which is 1453477 and let say I want to calculate prevalence for people who has diabetes and there is 851415 people who applies to that condition.
so 851415/1453477=0.58577 but when I run the query below I am keep getting 1 for the answer.

```
select count(disease__id) / count(person_id) as prevalence
from disease
where disease_id=12345;
```

I know that disease_id for diabetes is 12345 and there is 851415 people who are diabetes so 'count(disease_id)' should be 851415 and 'count(person_id)' should result 1453477.

can some one please help me on this?

Comment: try this select count(disease__id)*1.0 / count(person_id)*1.0 as prevalence
from disease
where disease_id=12345;

Comment: I am still getting same answer,1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use this.

```
select
  cast (
    (
      select
        count(disease__id)
      from
        disease
      where
        disease_id = 12345
    ) as decimal
  )
) / (select count(person_id) from disease)
```

Comment: I am still getting 1 for the output..

Comment: updated, please try